# How was the S-IVB stage configured for the post-extraction retrograde dump?

Tags: apollo-program, propulsion, saturn-v

When answering [How exactly did the separation between Saturn V stage 3 and the Command / Lunar Module work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40497/how-exactly-did-the-separation-between-saturn-v-stage-3-and-the-command-lunar) I first wrote that the retrograde dump after LM extraction happened "through the engine".

But upon reflection and some searching, I could not confirm that the dump happened through the engine (although I suspect it did).

So, how were the systems in the S-IVB stage configured to create "Thrust from available propellants in the launch vehicle auxiliary propulsion system and from main propulsion system venting"? Were valves opened in the J-2 engine and the tanks pressurized, or was it done through a vent system? And was the auxiliary propulsion system fired simo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to various bits of information from Apollo Flight Journals (Apollo- 8, 10 to 13 and 15):

- LH2 was dumped propulsively through Continuous Vent System (very small delta-v).
- LOX and pressurizing helium were propulsively dumped through the J-2 engine bell.
- in addition to the above, Auxiliary Propulsion System (two ullage motors) were mentioned to be fired in some of the missions.

Some quotes from the respective Apollo Flight Journals:

[Apollo-8](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap08fj/03day1_green_sep.html)

> ...remaining **LOX** in the tank will be **vented through the engine bell**. This dump will begin at 005:07:56. Additionally, the **APS thrusters will fire until depletion** and the various bottles and spheres of pressurising gases will be vented. Overall the S-IVB's velocity will be changed by 41.9 metres/second.
>
> Mission Control are about to start venting the remains of the **liquid hydrogen** in the S-IVB's fuel tank. This vent **will make little difference to the stage's trajectory**.
>
> 005:06:48 Borman: The S-IVB has started [to] dump. [Long pause.]
>
> [As well as the LOX being dumped from the S-IVB, the **remaining contents of the start bottle on the J-2 engine are also dumped** at this time.]
>
> 005:25:32
>   the **ullage motors within the APS engines** at the base of the S-IVB begin firing to add their remaining impulse to the stage's slingshot maneuver. The engines **will burn for just over 12 minutes until their propellant is depleted**.

[Apollo-10](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap10fj/as10-day1-pt5-lmext-sivb-sep.html)

> This will be a 19.7 feet per second burn with the service propulsion system, the big engine in the service module, retrograde burn. It will put the S-IVB out ahead of the Apollo 10 spacecraft, the dock configuration. Then shortly after the burn the **remaining propellants in the S-IVB** will be **vented through the engine**, be a propulsive vent.

[Apollo-11](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/03tde.html)

> 005:13:51 McCandless: Roger. They're continuing with the non-propulsive vent from the liquid oxygen tank. It would be radially opposite, there. And Booster tells me it's the continuous vent system. They're also dumping a small amount of fuel at this time. We've got about 23½ minutes or so until **the APS burn**. Over.

[Apollo-12](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/03tde.html)

> Twelve minutes after ejection the S-IVB **will perform an evasive maneuver using its auxiliary propulsion system**, about a 10 foot per second maneuver, essentially retrograde.
>
> 004:26:53 Carr: **Ullage motors are on**. [Pause.]
>   ...
>
> 004:28:13 Carr: 12, Houston. The APS maneuver is complete.
>
> The S-IVB **sling shot maneuver** was scheduled for 4 hours, 48 minutes elapsed time. The present elapsed time is 4 hours, 39 minutes. During this maneuver, the remaining **liquid oxygen** in the propellant tanks of the S-IVB **is dumped**. Though **the engine bell** does provide small amount of energy, it will cause the S-IVB to go around the trailing edge of the moon and then into a solar orbit.

[Apollo-13](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap13fj/03tde.html)

> [This is Apollo Control at 4 hours, 37 minutes. We're now about 3 minutes away from the scheduled LOX dump, the **propulsive vent of liquid oxygen through the engine nozzle** of the S-IVB. The Saturn Instrument Unit will command this maneuver or command the LOX dump and the **LOX will flow out the engine bell** for 48 seconds or until the tank is empty whichever comes first. The preliminary plan would be for the LOX dump to produce a change in velocity of about 28 feet per second [8.5 m/s] which would contribute to the trajectory change placing the S-IVB on an impacting trajectory with the Moon and **subsequent midcourse corrections using the two** 70-pound thrust [311-newton] **Auxiliary Propulsion System units** on the S-IVB would be intended to correct this trajectory and bring it into the precisely preplanned limits.]
>
> This is Apollo Control at 5 hours, 45 minutes. Our Booster systems engineers just reported that the first midcourse correction opportunity with the S-IVB, the **midcourse correction** designed to put the S-IVB on the proper impacting trajectory with the Moon, **will be required** and it is expected that **this maneuver will be a 217-second burn of the two Auxiliary Propulsion System modules** on the S-IVB.

[Apollo-15](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap15fj/03tde.html)

> [The S-IVB is maneuvering to the propellant dump attitude. The thrust from this **dump of propellant and pressurising helium** gives a planned change in velocity of 10 metres per second.]
>
> [The S-IVB has begun **venting LH2 via the CVS (Continuous Vent System)**, imparting a *slight Delta-V of 0.42 m/s*.]
>
> [The **LOX dump** is initiated simply **by opening the engine's main LOX valve and allowing it to vent through the single J-2 rocket motor**. The greater atomic weight of the venting *oxygen helps to impart a Delta-V of 9.14 m/s*. The **dumping of helium from the high pressure storage** spheres *adds another 1.37 m/s* alteration to the S-IVB's trajectory. Both of these accelerations help to target the stage to its planned impact site.]

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer, thanks!  After I wrote the question I found some info in the third stage test plan https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700027461.pdf which might be of some interest to you.  The information you found is better, though.